# Remove Metadata From EXE compiled in VS13

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a small program that has been compiled to an executable on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013. The program works just fine, but I would like to remove all the metadata from the executable. If, for example, I use the powershell command,

Get-Content program.exe

It outputs strings like the full project path, copyright information, etc. Is there an option in Visual Studio that I can select not to include that information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove personal information from an ".exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660929/remove-personal-information-from-an-exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I found the setting I was looking for here:

Project >Configuration > Build > Advanced > Debug Info = None

Answer (score 1):

You could use a program like upx to strip out metadata as well as compress the binary, but also compiling in release mode without including debugging information should remove the majority of the information included.

Comment: I went to Build > Configuration Manager and changed Configuration to Release, but it still includes metadata. Is there some other setting I need to change?

Comment: Actually I found where I needed to change the settings. It was in Project >Configuration > Build > Advanced > Debug Info = None