# Remove debug information from an ".exe"

Tags: c#, exe

If I put my C# program exe in a text editor, I can find debug information in it:

[image]

How can I remove that?

EDIT: I dont care about the pdb file, i only care about that there is a path to the pdb file in the executable. This path contains my name (coincidence in this example), my question is how i can remove THAT Path from the executable, NOT how to remove the pdb file itself.

Comment: very funny... the compiler/linker does that. @SinOfficial, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371032/c-sharp-release-version-has-still-pdb-file

Comment: How is debugging information "personal information"?

Comment: because it contains an absolute path revealing the user name of the profile that compiled it. which *is* worth consideration.

Comment: The easiest way is to move your project to another location on the disk, and recompile. See also [how to clear PDB string in a release VC++ build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32790375/33499).

Comment: Honestly, who keeps their source code in **My Documents** anyway?  That's the first option I change

Comment: **This is not a duplicate**.  OP want to know why and how to remove potentially sensitive information (pure coincidence in his example) from the exe.  It took me a while too to realise what the OP wanted. Contrary to what it says above I never voted as duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

---

OK, so yours is actually a curious question because what you are asking for is really nothing you normally would be concerned about.  **PDB files are not "personal information"** and **neither** is the **path** found **in the .exe that points to the .PDB file**.  Your example is pure coincidence.    Moving on...

---

### Easiest fix Based on Best Practices

Don't keep your Visual Studio code inside your Windows User Profile **Documents** folder.  Instead move it to one of the following

- **c:\development** or better yet, a folder on a non-OS drive if you can
- When you are ready to ship, ensure you build your code on a CI server. In this day and age there is no excuse for not using a CI server in the same way as you should be using source control

That will fix the coincidental username appearing in your exe.  Unless of course you are running your build agent in your user context instead of a dedicated build account.

Also, I like to keep **Documents** for, well documents and not get polluted with code;  Git or SVN caches.  It just creates noise for real-time back-up apps like *CrashPlan*.

### Alternative

Just build **without debug information**.

Consider this default debug build, note the path to the associated PDB File:

[image]

### Release with No debug settings

[image]

### Settings

[image]

Yours is a **debug** build which you can tell by the path to the **PDB** file, a file containing debug information about the application.   Normally you don't deploy a debug build of your application.

Make a **release** build of your application.  Release builds by default do not generate a .pdb file.

Also, .pdb files don't give away "source code" to avid readers if that is your fear.  At most it may list the path to a file, but a filepath doesn't constitute source code content.

### See also:

- You might want to check this out as to [why its a good idea to always deploy PDB files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307544/585968)

Comment: I dont care about the pdb file... I care about the name in the path. But your solution worked. thanks

Comment: @MickyD hahaha pdb stands for personal information hahahah very funny. do you really think that i thought that?

Comment: @SinOfficial No, but when you build with **Full info** or **.pdb** only in either **debug** or **release**, guess what - whilst the exe contains a full path to the .pdb file; the pdb file contains full paths to **all the original file paths to your source code when you compiled your app**.  As **dlatikay** correctly points out, such a path is going to include in your case, your usename profile just out of **pure coincidence**.  So there is that

Comment: You can also remove the path to the PDB file by including it in the EXE file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230666/9134997

Comment: @MichaelHutter true, but for release builds who wants a huge .EXE file instead of deploying an _optional_ .PDB file?   PDBs were designed for this reason.